# Redirects aren't working, is there a conflict with the rules or order of them?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect any incoming traffic that is not www or https, to www and https.
The one issue is trying to add one more rule that would handle all traffic that used to be at rootdomain.com/blog/rest-of-url-title and send that to the subdomain https://blog.rootdomain.com/rest-of-url-title

This is what I have in my root domain htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)$ https://blog.rootdomain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

Then within the blog subdomain directory htaccess I have this (to redirect any non https to https and the rest is Wordpress based)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When trying to hit any url that is rootdomain.com/blog/rest-of-url-title it redirects to 
https://www.rootdomain.com/index.php

Instead of redirecting to the blog subdomain, it just goes to www and since that url title doesn't exist for www i just get 404.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go with mod_alias redirectmatch to get it working how i wanted

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/blog/(.*)$ https://blog.rootdomain.com/$1
```

It's odd because the mod_rewrite line in my original htaccess in root had this:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) https://blog.rootdomain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Which did not work on this particular server, but worked fine on any other servers I tested on. Maybe because of a subdomain/directory mapping issue?

Regardless, I know it's not good practice to mix mod_rewrite and mod_alias, this final worked for me:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/blog/(.*)$ https://blog.skodaminotti.com/$1
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

Would still love to hear if anyone knows why the rewriterule wouldn't work.